# How do I configure pycharm to "gray out" excluded folders?

Tags: python, pycharm

How do I configure pycharm to "gray out" excluded folders rather than just removing them from the project view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not possible at the moment, [there is an open feature request](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-23537) to provide semi-excluded folders.

**UPDATE:** if you need to mark certain directories/files with specific colors or not show them in all the views, consider using the [Scopes feature](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/webhelp/scope.html).

Answer (score 1):

With new version of Pycharm it is possible to "gray out" a folder while still keep it in your project view. (if that's what you're asking for)

You can simply right-click the folder in your project view and "Mark directory as excluded."

You can then chose to show/not to show excluded folders/files with the setting button on the project view panel.

Refer this official documentation for more options: https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-ignored-files.html

Answer (score 0):

meanwhile it is possible to mark directories or single files as "excluded" so they become "invisible" for PyCharm. just right-click the item and select form the context menu *Mark Directory As > Excluded*

PyCharm help reference: [link](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/configuring-folders-within-a-content-root.html#d916122e117)